# Issue when executing a gradle script

Tags: mongodb, gradle, groovy

I got an error when I am trying to execute the below gradle task.

```
task runScript (dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = "packageName.fileName"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Gradle version: 4.10.2

Java version: 9.0.1

Is it anything with Java Configuration or so?

> Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
>   org/codehaus/groovy/ast/MethodCallTransformation

Comment: What version of Gradle? Can you post the full output, not a screenshot of part of a terminal?

Comment: You probably don't have any class named `packageName.fileName`. Read the rest of the error message you get, and do what it suggests you to do. If you still don't understand, post all the relevant output, **as text**.

Comment: The filenames are correct, I posted the whole output as text

Comment: Are you using spring boot?